# How to conserve natural fruit juices without alcohol?

Tags: freshness

Sorry if this is not the proper place to ask this. I would like to produce some natural fruit juices to sell, and it must last at least a week once bottled.

It will be made with natural fruit, water, and sugar. I would prefer it to be AS NATURAL AS POSSIBLE.

**What can be added to help preserve it longer (as natural as possible)?**

Answer (score 3):

This is basically making must but not adding yeast to it and making wine.

I would do one of three things to your juice:

1. Boil the juice(must), or heat to 85 deg C for 15 min, then bottle into sterilised bottles.
2. Treat with a Campden Tablet, then again bottle into sterilised bottles.
3. Pasteurise after bottling as EZ suggests.

Comment: I would like to go for the pasteurization, but how can I change so much the temperatures without breaking the glass bottle?

Comment: https://www.leaf.tv/articles/how-to-pasteurize-juice-at-home/

Comment: Yes, this is basically about "pasteurization"...